# Convert List[Seq[String]] to Map[K,V] Scala

Tags: scala, dictionary, apache-spark

I am writing my data to Kibana from Spark by creating a Map. My data type is `List[Seq[String]]`. But instead of just mapping the key to value, I get keys and multiple values assigned to them. So in the end instead of one value corresponding to the key and multiple records, I get multiple values corresponding to the key and multiple records, because this process is repeated. So the data looks like this:

```
event_name:"Sketch-Up at Field Museum (DRY MEDIA ONLY)", "Watercolor Basics - Part 2!", "Watercolor Basics (Intro Class)", "Jan: How about a FREE day trip to Mexico? Did I say FREE?", "Dia de Los muertos Day of the dead" 
venue_name:"The Field Museum", "filmfront", "filmfront", "National Museum of Mexican Art", "Dvorak Park (Pilsen)" 
distance:3116.147997575436, 3896.341529919854, 3896.341529919854, 3974.197798056245, 2615.3793888968457
```

While I want to have something like this for one record:

```
event_name:"Sketch-Up at Field Museum (DRY MEDIA ONLY)" 
venue_name:"The Field Museum" 
distance:3116.147997575436
```

Here is my code for the map creation:

```
val resultsMap = Map(
    "group_name" -> resultsList.map(sublist => sublist(0)), 
    "event_name" -> resultsList.map(sublist => sublist(1)),  
    "venue_name" -> resultsList.map(sublist => sublist(2)),
    "distance" -> resultsList.map(sublist => sublist(3))
)
```

Where `resultsList: List[Seq[String]]`

What am I doing wrong while converting the list to the map?

Comment: Please provide more clarification.

Comment: What's the type you expect to get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that you weren't entirely clear on what kind of result you expect, nor what's the actual input, so I had to make some assumptions. Please be more specific next time you ask a question.

Currently you create a single `Map` and put each element of a sequence as a list under the same key:

```scala
val resultsMap = Map(...)
```

In other words all your sequence elements are aggregated by their position under a single key.

You mentioned you expect them to be separate, so I assume you want a `List` (or `Seq`) of records, each being a `Map`. You can't get a single map as a result, as keys cannot be duplicated in maps.

You can easily arrive at such a result by mapping your list of sequenes to a list of maps:

```scala
val resultsList = List(
  Seq("A", "Sketch-Up at Field Museum (DRY MEDIA ONLY)", "The Field Museum", "3116.147997575436"),
  Seq("A", "Watercolor Basics - Part 2!", "filmfront", "3896.341529919854"),
  Seq("B", "Watercolor Basics (Intro Class)", "filmfront", "3896.341529919854"),
  Seq("B", "Jan: How about a FREE day trip to Mexico? Did I say FREE?", "National Museum of Mexican Art", "3974.197798056245"),
  Seq("A", "Dia de Los muertos Day of the dead", "Dvorak Park (Pilsen)", "2615.3793888968457")
)


val finalResult = resultsList map { s => Map(
  "group_name" -> s(0),
  "event_name" -> s(1),
  "venue_name" -> s(2),
  "distance" -> s(3)
)}
```

The result:

```scala
List(
  Map(group_name -> A, event_name -> Sketch-Up at Field Museum (DRY MEDIA ONLY), venue_name -> The Field Museum, distance -> 3116.147997575436), 
  Map(group_name -> A, event_name -> Watercolor Basics - Part 2!, venue_name -> filmfront, distance -> 3896.341529919854), 
  Map(group_name -> B, event_name -> Watercolor Basics (Intro Class), venue_name -> filmfront, distance -> 3896.341529919854), 
  Map(group_name -> B, event_name -> Jan: How about a FREE day trip to Mexico? Did I say FREE?, venue_name -> National Museum of Mexican Art, distance -> 3974.197798056245), 
  Map(group_name -> A, event_name -> Dia de Los muertos Day of the dead, venue_name -> Dvorak Park (Pilsen), distance -> 2615.3793888968457)
)
```

Comment: It's exactly what I needed. Thank you very much!